# 3D Mandelbrot - Multibrot

Tags: fractals

The basic Mandelbrot equation is well known $f(z) = z^2 + c$.

The formula for the 'MultiBrot' or 'MandelShape' varies the value '$2$' in the formula $f(z) = z^d + c$.

There are other descriptives for 3D versions of the Mandelbrot fractal but sadly these more commonly take the form of mere colouration - however pretty.

The attached link shows an animation of the Multibrot from $-8$ to $8$.  What I am interested in is seeing how this would look from other than the simple vertical overview being shown; clearly this would be an infinite tower from the ring at $-1000$ and the fuzzy circle at $+1000$ (infinity) - so a choice of values and slice must be made.

Ideas please? 
JK

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lM5chKSP_6s&feature=related

Comment: The closest to a true 3D mandelbrot is the mandelbulb: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbulb.

Comment: I do not deny the existence of the MandelBulb but the simpler progression available by simply varying the power value '2' generates a more understandable sequence.  I suspect I feel that your definition of 'closest' is actually subjective?!

Comment: Subjective, yes. The "issue" with just introducing a parameter, is that it will not behave fractally in the vertical direction - it will be smooth, more like a sweep. That's the problem of most attempts at generalization, and the mandelbulb was one of the ways to get something that has fractal nature in both dimensions on the "surface" (broccoli-like structure instead of sheet wrinkles). But of course, it depends on what you want - your proposal is just another option to explore and study.

Comment: Completely agree. The MandelBulb does have fractality (? new word) in all directions but the Multibrot still interests me and it does have a simpler to understand formula change than the MBulb.   I have no idea how a view could be done from a not-overview angle - but i'd like to see it done.

Comment: If you were to try to ray-trace using distance estimates, I suppose you would need a bound on how much the distance in the $c$ plane can change by as you vary $d$.  I suspect this bound doesn't exist, which might make this approach a dead end... Perhaps voxel or mesh generation, from a sequence of images or otherwise, is the best that can be done.

Comment: Claude - thanks but I understood only the first 6 words ..... THAT's how short I am of mathematical comprehension!

Comment: @JKing http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/index.php/2011/06/distance-estimated-3d-fractals-part-i/ explains the first phrase. The bound part is that for the 2D distance estimate (within each plane where $d$ is constant) to be extended into 3D, it shouldn't change "too much" when you change $d$ by a small amount. Voxels are to 3D what a bitmap is to 2D.  A mesh is a surface made of triangles.

Answer (score 2):

I've been exploring such slices through Multibrot space with my own application. This is 2D-only, and can specify an arbitrary angle, offset, and rotation. The image is a 90-degree "vertical" slice through the space, where the imaginary component is held a zero, the real component changes along the X axis, and the exponent changes along the Y axis. The result is not "smooth," but displays the same complexity as the more traditional views "from the top."

Vertical Slice through Multibrot Space

[image]

The application is http://www.fractaleverywhere.com

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to render 3D fractals by ray-marching with distance estimators. The distance estimate tells you, given a point, how far the nearest point in the fractal is.  The ray-marching algorithm calculates the distance from a point on the ray (in any direction, not necessarily the ray direction), and steps the ray forward by this amount, thus the ray gets closer and closer to the object (or passes by it and hits the background).

Syntopia has a blog with a series of posts on [Distance Estimated 3D Fractals](http://blog.hvidtfeldts.net/index.php/2011/06/distance-estimated-3d-fractals-part-i/), applicable within the software Fragmentarium and its updated fork [FragM](https://github.com/3Dickulus/FragM).  FragM 2.0.0 has a `Complex.frag` with complex [dual numbers for automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number#Differentiation).  Using FragM's DE Raytracer, a "Multibrot Stack" distance estimator can be implemented like this:

```
uniform float Iterations;     // e.g. 100
uniform float EscapeRadius;   // e.g. 30
uniform float DistanceFactor; // e.g. 0.5
float DE(vec3 position)
{
  vec4 c = vec4(position.xy, 1.0, 0.0);
  float d = position.z;
  vec4 z = c;
  int i = 0;
  float r = length(z.xy); // r = |z|
  while(r < Bailout && (i < Iterations))
  {
    z = cExp(cLog(z) * d) + c; // z = z^d + c
    r = length(z.xy); // r = |z|
    i++;
  }
  float dr = length(z.zw); // dr = |dz/dc|
  // compute scaled distance estimate
  return 0.5 * log(r) * r / dr * DistanceFactor;
}
```

Note the use of the `DistanceFactor` variable to scale the distance estimate.  This is to try to mitigate the inherent problem with this approach: the distance estimate is only valid in the plane where the power $d$ is constant, but the ray direction in general has varying $d$.  Small changes in $d$ might lead to large changes in the distance estimate, but hopefully the change is bounded above by a constant factor.

There is another problem: non-integer powers of complex numbers are multivalued, because complex $\log$ is multi-valued (the imaginary part can have arbitrary integer multiples of $2 \pi$ added to it).  This leads to the "cut" that appears along the negative X axis.  A proper rendering of the fractal (even in 2D with constant $d$) should better take into account the multiple values, but I don't know the best way to do this.

How does it look?  This animation took about 45 minutes to render at an acceptable quality (with `DistanceFactor = 0.5`):

[image: Multibrot Stack animation]